# Duplicated line output in log file

Tags: c#, .net, logging, cmd, output

I am writing cmd output results to a log file, and when I do so I get duplicated results. So what this is doing is grabbing a line from the standard output, if that string at least contains the text of the line, it will print in a log file that it's a success.

However, it is also including the first 4 instances which I don't want. I can see the issue as the else statement means that it will display "failure".

My question is, how do I only want the program to read a specific line only?

Here is my code:

```
 start = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");

            var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = "/c command here",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true
                }
            };

            process.Start();

            while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(line);

                if (line.Contains("Output goes here."))
                {
                    finish = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
                    PrintRow("Task 1", start, finish, "SUCCESS");
                    PrintLine();
                }

                else
                {
                    finish = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
                    PrintRow("Task 1", start, finish, "FAILURE");
                    PrintLine();
                }

                process.WaitForExit();
```

Log file results that I get:

### |  Task 1 |   15:23:25 PM   |   15:23:30 PM   |     FAILURE     |

### |  Task 1  |   15:23:25 PM   |   15:23:31 PM   |     FAILURE     |

### |  Task 1  |   15:23:25 PM   |   15:23:32 PM   |     FAILURE     |

### |  Task 1  |   15:23:25 PM   |   15:23:32 PM   |     FAILURE     |

### |  Task 1  |   15:23:25 PM   |   15:23:32 PM   |     SUCCESS     |

Answer (score 0):

FIgured this out

Changed `string line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();` to `string line = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();`